# How to transform .xml file values for dev,uat,prod environments in azure devops?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment

I know, we can use `File transforms and variable substitution Options` for `.config` file dynamic value modifications during release.

But I have a `.XML` file as below

```
<RPSServer>
 <Sites>
 <Site SiteName="default">
 <SiteId>123546</SiteId>
 <ReturnURL>Custome URL</ReturnURL>
 </Site>
 </Sites>
</RPSServer>
```

In above xml file, `SiteId` and `ReturnURL` will be different for DEV, UAT and PROD. How can I manage that in azure release definition.

Comment: For your question, the Replace Tokens task is the correct solution. You can check if it works for you.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Just want to confirm does the Shayki's solution is work for you? If it can help you achieve what you want, you can accept that answer thus other SO users could refer to know whether it is really works:-) if you still facing any other issue, kindly to leave comment there.

Comment: Is there any other alternative than tasks in Marketplace. We are not allowed to use Marketplace tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) extension. then keep placeholders like the prefix you specified in the extension task, for example: `<ReturnURL>_returnUrl_</ReturnURL>`.

[image]

Now in the variables put the value according to each stage:

[image]